# Is there a way to isolate single objects for more Cycles render samples?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers, noise-reduction

I'm animating a large scene, i.e., with many objects and light sources, with Cycles and struggling to solve noise issues. It's an outdoor scene with a real world twilight HDR sky and the darkness of the scene seems to make noise issues even more of an issue. I've tried a lot of noise solutions, including Blender's built-in Optix implementation and 3rd-party solutions, but it seems the only surefire way to reduce noise is via the brute force method of increasing render samples, but then that increases render time.

**In many instances, only a few of the objects are exhibiting significant noise artifacts, so my question is: Is there a way to isolate single objects for more render samples?**

I've been researching Blender's Render Layers as a way of separating noisy objects for more samples. If I could render those noisy object animations in isolation, then combine those renders in an external video editor, I might have a workable noise solution. However, those higher-sample renders would only be useful if the isolated noisy objects still received the lights and shadows of the larger scene. Can Render Layers do this? If not, is there another solution? Thanks. Blender 3.3.1, Windows 11

Comment: This is what adaptive sampling does.  If that produces problems I suppose you could do a separate pass and overlay it

Comment: @AllenSimpson Thank you for the response. Are you saying I could do a separate pass by moving the objects to a separate Scene with its own sample settings?

Comment: I never could determine an answer to my question, however this post-render solution is doing the job for me: https://www.neatvideo.com/